# Problems parsing xml with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, android-xml, androidhttpclient, android-xmlpullparser

I am getting the following error ".XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ["@1:3 "

when doing the following

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String jSONData = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        if (json.has("games"))
        {
            strJson = json.getString("games");
        }



        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(strJson));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
            {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                System.out.println("End document");
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                System.out.println("Start tag " + xpp.getName());
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            {
                System.out.println("End tag " + xpp.getName());
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
            {
                System.out.println("Text " + xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();//Here is Where I am getting error!!
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit:
Here is the JSON. I want to parse "games"

```
{
"sport": "NBA", 
"period": "20140420", 
"games": [
"<ticker-entry gamecode=\"2014042024\" gametype=\"Playoffs\"><visiting-team display_name=\"Dallas\" alias=\"Dal\" nickname=\"Mavericks\" id=\"6\" division=\"WCS\" conference=\"WC\" score=\"85\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"12\" team-fouls=\"2\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"32\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"21\" team-fouls=\"7\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"20\" team-fouls=\"6\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"85\"></score></visiting-team><home-team display_name=\"San Antonio\" alias=\"SA\" nickname=\"Spurs\" id=\"24\" division=\"WCS\" conference=\"WC\" score=\"90\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"21\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"22\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"22\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"25\" team-fouls=\"5\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"90\"></score></home-team><gamestate status=\"Final\" display_status1=\"Final\" display_status2=\"\" href=\"http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/nba/recap.asp?g=2014042024\" tv=\"TNT/FSSW\" gametime=\"1:00 PM\" gamedate=\"4/20\" is-dst=\"1\" is-world-dst=\"1\"></gamestate></ticker-entry>"
,"<ticker-entry gamecode=\"2014042014\" gametype=\"Playoffs\"><visiting-team display_name=\"Charlotte\" alias=\"Cha\" nickname=\"Bobcats\" id=\"30\" division=\"ECS\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"88\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"23\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"19\" team-fouls=\"6\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"23\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"23\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"88\"></score></visiting-team><home-team display_name=\"Miami\" alias=\"Mia\" nickname=\"Heat\" id=\"14\" division=\"ECS\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"99\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"19\" team-fouls=\"2\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"30\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"23\" team-fouls=\"1\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"27\" team-fouls=\"6\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"99\"></score></home-team><gamestate status=\"Final\" display_status1=\"Final\" display_status2=\"\" href=\"http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/nba/recap.asp?g=2014042014\" tv=\"ABC\" gametime=\"3:30 PM\" gamedate=\"4/20\" is-dst=\"1\" is-world-dst=\"1\"></gamestate></ticker-entry>"
,"<ticker-entry gamecode=\"2014042004\" gametype=\"Playoffs\"><visiting-team display_name=\"Washington\" alias=\"Was\" nickname=\"Wizards\" id=\"27\" division=\"ECS\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"102\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"24\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"24\" team-fouls=\"9\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"24\" team-fouls=\"5\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"30\" team-fouls=\"6\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"102\"></score></visiting-team><home-team display_name=\"Chicago\" alias=\"Chi\" nickname=\"Bulls\" id=\"4\" division=\"ECC\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"93\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"22\" team-fouls=\"7\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"32\" team-fouls=\"8\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"21\" team-fouls=\"2\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"18\" team-fouls=\"8\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"93\"></score></home-team><gamestate status=\"Final\" display_status1=\"Final\" display_status2=\"\" href=\"http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/nba/recap.asp?g=2014042004\" tv=\"TNT/CSNC/CSNB\" gametime=\"7:00 PM\" gamedate=\"4/20\" is-dst=\"1\" is-world-dst=\"1\"></gamestate></ticker-entry>"
,"<ticker-entry gamecode=\"2014042010\" gametype=\"Playoffs\"><visiting-team display_name=\"Portland\" alias=\"Por\" nickname=\"Trail Blazers\" id=\"22\" division=\"WCN\" conference=\"WC\" score=\"122\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"27\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"21\" team-fouls=\"3\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"25\" team-fouls=\"7\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"33\" team-fouls=\"10\"></score><score heading=\"OT\" value=\"16\" team-fouls=\"5\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"122\"></score></visiting-team><home-team display_name=\"Houston\" alias=\"Hou\" nickname=\"Rockets\" id=\"10\" division=\"WCS\" conference=\"WC\" score=\"120\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"20\" team-fouls=\"5\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"29\" team-fouls=\"7\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"30\" team-fouls=\"5\"></score><score heading=\"4\" value=\"27\" team-fouls=\"8\"></score><score heading=\"OT\" value=\"14\" team-fouls=\"4\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"120\"></score></home-team><gamestate status=\"Final\" display_status1=\"Final\" display_status2=\"OT\" href=\"http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/nba/recap.asp?g=2014042010\" tv=\"TNT/CSNH/KGW\" gametime=\"9:30 PM\" gamedate=\"4/20\" is-dst=\"1\" is-world-dst=\"1\"></gamestate></ticker-entry>"
]}
```

Comment: What's the document you're trying to parse? It sort of looks like you're trying to parse JSON with an XML parser here... But basically, the XML parser is telling you it can't parse the document, so to diagnose that we'll need to see the document.

Comment: Well, that's the main problem, then: the JSON element `games` doesn't contain XML directly, but is a JSON array of strings, each of which seem to contain XML (who invented this format!?) You probably want to iterate through that array with your JSON parser (I don't know which one you're using) and then parse each array value as XML. (The square brackets represent the JSON array, with the array elements separated by commas. Decode each of those to a string, and you should be able to parse the XML fragment `<ticker-entry>...</ticker-entry>` from each of those individually.)

Comment: Thx!Now how do I parse each array item?

Comment: That'll depend on which JSON parser you're using. I'm afraid I don't know much about any of them.